# How to regex strace process?

Tags: linux, strace

I'm trying to strace a multithereaded process with this command:

```
sudo strace -p1523 -e write -f
```

But it outputs a lot of unnecessary information example:

```
[pid  1166] write(6, "\26\3\1\2\0\1\0\1\374\3\3\247\321\336S\265c\321]\322\276\273\361]\24\313e\341c2a\334"..., 517) = 517
[pid  1166] write(6, "\26\3\3\0F\20\0\0BA\4\223\26\337\256\244\3429\306p\216\3231Zt\346xhi\343\261\215"..., 126) = 126
[pid  1166] write(6, "\27\3\3\1\230D\374\356\350\233O\305K\246\331`\311\300\265y\215\225\201\33\364\335\336\336\231\311z\355"..., 413) = 413
[pid  1166] write(6, "\25\3\3\0\32D\374\356\350\233O\305L\357\313\226\302$U?a\304\250s\264\16)\\\315N\270", 31) = 31
[pid  1166] write(1, "None\n", 5)       = 5
```

How I could trace only the text in in this regex  `write\(1, "(.*)", [0-9]*\)` ?

I tried with:

```
sudo strace -p1157 -e trace=/write\( -f

#output ------------
strace: regcomp: write(: Unmatched ( or \(

#also
sudo strace -p1157 -e trace=/write\(1.*\).* -f
#output ------------
strace: invalid system call '/write(1.*).*'
```

Are the strace regex different in some way?

Comment: It looks like the regex passed to `-e trace` is only matched against the name of the system call itself, not its arguments.  You can't pick out just some of the `write` calls this way.  Have you considered just filtering the output through `grep`?

Comment: I don't know how to use grep in this case

Comment: `strace -p1157 |& grep 'write(1,.*)'`.  Actually there's no need to match the entire string so you can just do `strace -p1557 |& grep 'write(1,'`

Comment: It doesn't work, grep returns nothing

Comment: It works for me with bash.  Are you using bash or a different shell?  (It should still be `sudo strace...` of course.)

Comment: I tried this on a raspberry pi (raspibian os) and my laptop (linux mint 19.3)... It does not work

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/$$/cmdline` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
sudo strace -f -p1523 -e write 2>&1 | grep -o 'write([^)]\+)'
```

or with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
sudo strace -f -p1523 -e write |& grep -o 'write([^)]\+)'
```

## Output

```
write(6, "\26\3\1\2\0\1\0\1\374\3\3\247\321\336S\265c\321]\322\276\273\361]\24\313e\341c2a\334"..., 517)
write(6, "\26\3\3\0F\20\0\0BA\4\223\26\337\256\244\3429\306p\216\3231Zt\346xhi\343\261\215"..., 126)
write(6, "\27\3\3\1\230D\374\356\350\233O\305K\246\331`\311\300\265y\215\225\201\33\364\335\336\336\231\311z\355"..., 413)
write(6, "\25\3\3\0\32D\374\356\350\233O\305L\357\313\226\302$U?a\304\250s\264\16)
write(1, "None\n", 5)
```

Comment: cat /proc/$$/cmdline 
outputs :  bash and the regex only worked for 1 time after that, run it again id didn't work

Comment: Maybe pid changed ? `-p1523`

Comment: @VasylYovdiy.  You still need the `-f` of course, don't forget that.  Perhaps you could post the precise command you're typing and a more precise description of what happens than just "didn't work".